# Karate gatling report is not generating

Tags: karate

I am using the Karate gatling plugin. Versions are below

```
 <karate.version>0.9.2</karate.version>
        <gatling.plugin.version>3.0.2</gatling.plugin.version>
```

The simulation file is generated but the report is not.

I have tried different injection profiles.  This only seems to happen if I use

```
atOnceUsers(10)
```

If I use

```
rampUsers(10) during (10 seconds)
```

Then the report is generated

```
Simulation Log
RUN performance.Load    load    1554325872173       3.0.2
USER    login   1   START   1554325872556   1554325872556
USER    login   2   START   1554325872808   1554325872808
USER    login   3   START   1554325872816   1554325872816
USER    login   4   START   1554325872827   1554325872827
USER    login   5   START   1554325872850   1554325872850
USER    login   6   START   1554325872858   1554325872858
USER    login   7   START   1554325872867   1554325872867
USER    login   8   START   1554325872873   1554325872873
USER    login   9   START   1554325872879   1554325872879
USER    login   10  START   1554325872885   1554325872885
USER    login   1   END 1554325872556   1554325874166
USER    login   9   END 1554325872879   1554325874166
USER    login   10  END 1554325872885   1554325874167
USER    login   3   END 1554325872816   1554325874191
USER    login   6   END 1554325872858   1554325874194
USER    login   2   END 1554325872808   1554325874215
USER    login   8   END 1554325872873   1554325874221
USER    login   4   END 1554325872827   1554325874224
USER    login   7   END 1554325872867   1554325874251
USER    login   5   END 1554325872850   1554325874261

Error
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
        at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:49)
        at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:76)
        at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:55)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:82)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:47)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

Expect the report to be generated

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate, please follow this process and you can use the `karate-gatling-demo` project as a base: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: this was a bug in Karate - can you refer this issue (fixed): https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/721